# Selecting numbers after point in double

Tags: c#

Как можно взять числа после запятой, т.е., к примеру, есть число 0,00123 мне надо 00123?

Comment: Что значит числа? Последовательность цифр? Задачи из школьной информатики.

Comment: Отмечайте подхоящие ответы "принятыми", здесь так принято. У вас 21 вопрос и ни один ответ не принят.

Comment: @lalal дробная часть

      number - Math.Truncate(number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предложу такой вариант:

```
public static string GetFraction(double d)
{
    string doubleString = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int startPos = doubleString.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
    string result = "";
    if (startPos > 0)
    {
        result = doubleString.Substring(startPos, doubleString.Length - startPos);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
double N = 1.0000323; //Входное число
string temp = N.ToString(); // создаем строку, в которой записано это число
string[] tempArr = temp.Split('.'); //Разделяем строку на 2 части
string Number = tempArr[1];  //Второй элемент массива - строка "0000323"
```

А дальше это можно парсить и перебирать символы строки с помощью foreach

Comment: плохой метод - не сработает на американской локализации (хотя автору врят ли нужно париться по этому поводу).

Лучше сделать ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) и Split('.').

И этот код вобще не скомпилится - литерал double пишется через точку.

Comment: Да, с точкой перепутал. Уже исправил. 

А при чем тут американская локализация? Что поменяется?

Comment: ToString() работает в зависимости от текущей локали. Для русской он поставит разделителем запятую, для американской - точку, у испанцев, вроде еще каждую тысячу будет отделять запятой, а у немцев вроде как будет отделять тысячи пробелом.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал!)